# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: uid

Tags: python, sqlite

i created a sqlite table in python with this code

```
db.execute('CREATE TABLE const (uid INT UNIQUE ,article INT, sub INT, content TEXT)')
```

i tried to do a select-where state on the table using this code

```
cursor = db.execute('SELECT sub FROM const WHERE uid = ?', uid)
```

and all i get is this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: uid
```

i tried search but there seems to be no clear explanation and solution to this error for a newbie like me. Please help

here goes my code

```
#!/usr/lib/python3m

import sqlite3


article = 0
sub = 0
text = ''
count = 0
flag = False
close_tag = False


def close():
    global text
    global close_tag

    if close_tag:
        a = 0
        while a < count:
            a += 1
            text += '</ol>'
    close_tag = False


def get():
    close()
    # out = open('output.txt', 'a')
    # print('Article: ' + str(article), end='', file=out)
    # print('\n' + 'Sub: ' + str(sub) + '\n', end='', file=out)
    # print(text + '\n', file=out, end='')

    # print('Article: ' + str(article), end='')
    # print('\n' + 'Sub: ' + str(sub) + '\n', end='')
    # print(text + '\n', end='')


    db = sqlite3.connect('const_enGB')
    # if not (article == a and sub == s):
    uid = int(str(article) + str(sub))
    cursor = db.execute('SELECT sub FROM const WHERE uid = ?', uid)
    if not cursor:
        db.execute('INSERT INTO const (uid, article, sub, content) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', uid, article, sub, text))
    else:
        db.execute('UPDATE const SET article = ?, sub =?, content=? WHERE uid = ? ',     (article, sub, text))
    db.commit()


def main():
    file = open('ch1.txt')
    global article
    global text
    global sub
    global count
    global flag
    global close_tag
    article = 0
    sub = 0
    text = ''
    count = 0
    flag = False
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line != '':
            if line.isnumeric():
                article = line
                text = ''
            else:
                ol = False
                start = line.find('(') + 1
                end = line.find(')')
                t = line[start:end]
                if t.isnumeric():
                    ol = True
                    sub = int(line[start:end])
                    text = line[end + 1:len(line)].strip()
                elif line[start:end].isalpha():
                    ol = True
                    flag = False
                    close_tag = True
                    type_of = line[start:end]
                    if type_of == 'a':
                        text += '<ol type="a"><li>' + line[end + 1:len(line)].strip() + '</li>'
                        count = 1
                        flag = True
                    elif 'i' == type_of:
                        text += '<ol type="i"><li>' + line[end + 1:len(line)].strip() + '</li>'
                        count = 2
                        flag = True
                    else:
                        if not flag:
                            text += '<li>' + line[end + 1:len(line)].strip() + '</li>'
                if not ol:
                    text += line[end + 1:len(line)].strip()

        if sub != 0 and article != 0 and text.strip() != '':
            if not flag:
                get()


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: Can you show us *actual*, *runnable* code that reproduces this problem? It's possible that the problem is actually with you code, but there's no way for us to tell.

Comment: A theory; it would seem there likely already exists a table with the same name and no uid column. That way, the create fails and since uid is not created, so does the query. If the table exists and actually looks like you're intending, there's nothing wrong with the query.